# Difference between normal php and compiled php?

Tags: php

when I read php documentation, I have often seen the word **compiled php**, for example:

> mysqli support is available only if you have **compiled PHP** with the
>   **--with-mysqli=path/to/mysql_config** option.

- so what is the difference between the **normal php** and **compiled
  php**?
- why we need compiled php?
- how to compile php?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the context you're describing, compiled is a verb, not an adjective.  It's saying that you have to have compiled the PHP interpreter program with specific options.

PHP is an interpreter, which is a normal program that accepts PHP code as input and displays the result as output.  The interpreter must be compiled from source code just like any other program.  Most people don't ever do this, but hardcore developers might make changes to satisfy their burning desire to realize their vision of a perfect PHP interpreter.

One of the things you can do is compile the PHP interpreter with a number of options.  This just means that slightly different code is compiled into the final PHP interpreter.  When the documentation describes compilation options, it's just warning you that some features can't work unless you compile with those options enabled.

Comment: Thanks, Kevin. I seem to understand your explanation little by little, but how to compile the PHP interpreter with desired option?

Comment: So, PHP is an open source project.  They maintain a mirror of the sourcecode on github: https://github.com/php/php-src